# Destroy deep associated object on parent save, using assign_attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I want to delete an deep associated record inside **assign_attributes**.

`Screen` is the only object I need to save, but the deep associated `NoteMember` object should get deleted on save of `Screen` object, if `params[:delete]` is **true** for that particular `NoteMember` object.

Following is the table structure:

**MODELS**

```
class Screen < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :alerts

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :alerts
end

class Alert < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :notes

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :notes
end

class Note < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :note_members

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :note_members
end

class NoteMember < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

**CONTROLLER**

```
s = Screen.where(id: <some_id>).first

alert_attrs = []

params[:alerts].each do |a|
  notes_attrs = []

  params[:notes].each do |n|
    note_member_attrs = []

    params[:note_members].each do |nm|
      # if nm[:delete] = true, I need to delete the note member on saving Screen object
      note_member_attrs.push({
        id: nm[:id],
        visibility: nm[:visibility]
      })
    end

    notes_attrs.push({
      id: n[:id],
      description: n[:description],
      note_members_attributes: note_member_attrs
    })
  end

  alert_attrs.push({
    id: a[:id],
    name: a[:name]
    notes_attributes: notes_attrs
  })
end

s.assign_attributes(
  alerts_attributes: alert_attrs
)

s.save!
```

How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use rails built-in destroy functionality:

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :note_members, allow_destroy: true
```

and pass

```rb
note_members_attributes: [ { _destroy: true, id: 123 }]
```

for `note_members` that need to be deleted.